# What does the 'do' special form do?

Tags: clojure, special-form

Documentation says:

> **(do exprs*)**
>   Evaluates the expressions in order and returns the value of the last. If no expressions are     supplied, returns nil.

However, I just did this:

```
(defn blah []
  (print "how")
  (print "now")
  (print "brown")
  (print "cow")
  (+ 1 1))
```

Resulting in this:

> hownowbrowncow2

So why is this thing needed again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it in forms like `if`, which only takes a single s-exp as "then" or "else".

```
(if (= a b)
    (do (println "Yes") (something))
    (do (println "No") (something-else)))
```

Comment: I'd add that there is an implicit `do` in a `defn` (or a `when`).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, [`do`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#do) is a special form that allows one to execute several forms in order, presumably for side-effects, because `do` form returns result of evaluation of its last form, so that there is no reason to use it with pure functions. Simply put, you can think of `do` as of some kind of wrapper for non-pure code. There are analogues of this form in every Lisp, for example in Common Lisp it is called `progn`.

`do` is implicitly used in such macros as: [`defn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defn), [`when`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/when), [`when-not`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/when-not), and others.

From practical point of view, you can use it with `if` statements (see [Tomo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26036415/3687048)) and it comes in handy when you write macros that have 'body' arguments (like body of a function in `defn`).

Comment: Any idea why `do` is implemented as special form and not as a macro? As I can see, it is pretty easy to implement such a macro...